# R: How to extract some large numbers, but not others, from data frame

Tags: regex, r, string

I have tried using gsub to solve this, but this is way too difficult. I do not know how to tell the function to return only certain numbers, but not others.

My problem:
I have a large data frame which has one column of test.comments for every performed test. It is a large chunk of text, out of which only certain numbers are of interest to me.

Example:

> **  POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS  ** INTERPRETATION: A calculated 18,900,000,000 BKV genome equivalents per ml urine were detected in this patient specimen....... ............................................................................................................................................ 1 out of 10 test samples... Call 555-122-634 with Questions

What I would like to do is add the value 18,900,000,000 (but not the phone number and other random numbers) in a separate column.

Sometimes, the number is surrounded by _______:

> ** POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS ** INTERPRETATION:  A CALCULATED__33,400,000____BK VIRUS (BKV) GENOME EQUIVALENTS PER ML WERE DETECTED

In some cases, the number is also small:

> A calculated   900   BK virus (BKV) genome equivalents per ml were detected in this patient specimen

or

> ** POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS ** INTERPRETATION:  A calculated__<250__________BK virus (BKV) genome equivalents per ml were detected in this patient specimen.

What I am hoping to have is a robust command that would return

18,900,000,000

33,400,000

900

<250

It would also help me to have a command that just returns numbers > 1,000 and I could manually edit the other cases.

But there must be a more elegant solution ?!?

edit: 
Thank you for your help everyone, Sven's solution worked best for me!

Comment: Each of the examples included "calculated" - is that *always* true?

Comment: So you want all the numbers that are not telephone numbers?

Comment: Well you could get all numbers with `lapply(strsplit(txt, "[ _<]"), grep, pattern="^\\d", value=TRUE)` and do some editing on that

Comment: In 95% of cases, it reads either 1) CALCULATED XXX,XXX,XXX or 2) Calculated XXX,XXX,XXX or 3) CALCULATED ___XXX,XXX____ / calculated __XXX,XXX_
some variants:
HIGH POSITIVE  The positive signal was greater than the highest point of the standard curve ... (>25 billion genome eq/ml urine).

or **  LOW POSITIVE ** The positive signal was less than the lowest point and a quantitative value cannot be determined (<250 genome eq/ml plasma)

These would ideally return > 25,000,000,000 and <250, respectively, however, for the most values, a variant of 'CALCULATED' is near the actual value of interest.

Comment: Not a regex pro, but this could prove helpful: [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/)

Comment: @jaysunice3401 - Thanks for the link, I am experimenting with it right now, very useful. the easiest way would probably to capture x amount of characters following calculated, and then extract ALL numbers from that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution with `sub`:

```
sub(".*?([<>]?[,0-9]+)[ _]+BK.*", "\\1", vec)
# [1] "18,900,000,000" "33,400,000"     "900"            "<250"
```

where `vec` is a vector containing the 4 examples.

Comment: Thank you, Sven, it works very well. In some reports there is a phrase: 
>THIS ASSAY`S SENSITIVITY AND SPECIFICITY FOR DETECTING BKV DNA HAVE BEEN FOUND TO BE 1 TO 10 BKV GENOME EQUIVALENTS PER UL. 

And in these cases, the command returns 10 instead of the actual number I wanted earlier, do you know how to fix it. Works great in the other cases!

Comment: @col.slade What is the expected output for this example?

Comment: Sorry, this is just the part that is interfering. The expected output is the actual number that is written earlier in the report:

** POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS ** INTERPRETATION: A CALCULATED_107,525,000____BK VIRUS (BKV) GENOME EQUIVALENTS PER ML WERE DETECTED. THIS ASSAY`S SENSITIVITY AND SPECIFICITY FOR DETECTING BKV DNA HAVE BEEN FOUND TO BE 1 TO 10 BKV GENOME EQUIVALENTS PER UL.

Expected output: 107,525,000
Actual output: 10

Comment: @col.slade I cannot reproduce this outcome. My command `sub(".*?([<>]?[,0-9]+)[ _]+BK.*", "\\1", "** POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS ** INTERPRETATION: A CALCULATED_107,525,000____BK VIRUS (BKV) GENOME EQUIVALENTS PER ML WERE DETECTED. THIS ASSAY'S SENSITIVITY AND SPECIFICITY FOR DETECTING BKV DNA HAVE BEEN FOUND TO BE 1 TO 10 BKV GENOME EQUIVALENTS PER UL")` returns `"107,525,000"`.

Comment: My bad, you are correct. The elements that return 10 are actually the ones that are negative. Your code solves my problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This will pull out the targets in those examples (added fourth case):

```
 dput(test)
c("** POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS ** INTERPRETATION: A calculated 18,900,000,000 BKV genome equivalents per ml urine were detected in this patient specimen....... ............................................................................................................................................ 1 out of 10 test samples... Call 555-122-634 with Questions", 
"** POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS ** INTERPRETATION: A CALCULATED__33,400,000____BK VIRUS (BKV) GENOME EQUIVALENTS PER ML WERE DETECTED", 
"A calculated 900 BK virus (BKV) genome equivalents per ml were detected in this patient specimen", 
"** POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS ** INTERPRETATION: A calculated__<250__________BK virus (BKV) genome equivalents per ml were detected in this patient specimen."
)
```

Need better example if this is not working well:

```
> gsub("(^[^>_0-9]+)([0-9,]{14}|[_]+[<0-9,]+[_]+|[,0-9]+ BK)(.+$)", 
       "\\2", test)
[1] "18,900,000,000 BK" "__33,400,000____"  "900 BK" 
[4] "__<250__________"
```

Then you can just remove the underscores and commas. The logic is that the reports seem to have a preset number of spaces for the data (which is all digits and commas if 14 characters or if not all digits are padded on either side with underscores.

Comment: Thank you, BondedDust. I tried your solution, and it works for approx 50% of the cases, but not all of them. Since I do not understand the expression I am not sure how to fix it. I think the reason is that in some reports, there are not 14 characters. The data were collected over several years and the lab may have updated there software: 

A calculated 5,750 BKV genome equivalents....

How would your solution have to be modified to include these reports < 14 digits ? Thanks again!

Comment: If you post a few more examples where it fails, you may get a better answer. May need to insert a fourth parenthetical pattern clause in the third position as ` BK)`. We can only work with what we are given.

Comment: BondedDust, your solution works in all cases in which '_' is used to pad the string to 14 digits. 

A calculated__2,950_________genome equivalents... ---> __2,950_________

It does not work in the cases when the report only has the actual number:

A calculated 5,750 BKV genome equivalents... --> output is the entire report

Comment: Perhaps adding `|[,0-9]+ BKV` to the middle set of the pattern. Seems to work for your offered cases so far.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches so far, neither are completely robust, and I'm not sure how to fix them since I'm not a good regexxxer

```
p1 <- "** POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS ** INTERPRETATION: A calculated 18,900,000,000 BKV genome equivalents per ml urine were detected in this patient specimen....... ............................................................................................................................................ 1 out of 10 test samples... Call 555-122-634 with Questions"
p2 <- "** POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS ** INTERPRETATION: A CALCULATED__33,400,000____BK VIRUS (BKV) GENOME EQUIVALENTS PER ML WERE DETECTED"
p3 <- "A calculated 900 BK virus (BKV) genome equivalents per ml were detected in this patient specimen

** POSITIVE FOR BK VIRUS ** INTERPRETATION: A calculated__<250__________BK virus (BKV) genome equivalents per ml were detected in this patient specimen."
```

This first one doesn't grab the 900 in the third example string

```
pattern <- '(?:\\s+)*[\\d<>]((?:[\\d,])*(?![\\s-\\d]))'
regmatches(p1, gregexpr(pattern, p1, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] " 18,900,000"

regmatches(p2, gregexpr(pattern, p2, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "33,400,000"

regmatches(p3, gregexpr(pattern, p3, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "<250"
```

This second one grabs extra number strings in the first example but does grab the 900 in the third example

```
pattern <- "[\\d<>]((?:[\\d,])*)"
regmatches(p1, gregexpr(pattern, p1, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "18,900,000,000" "1"              "10"             "555"           
# [5] "122"            "634"           

regmatches(p2, gregexpr(pattern, p2, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "33,400,000"

regmatches(p3, gregexpr(pattern, p3, perl = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "900"  "<250"
```

Comment: Y'ur a better regexer than me, Gunga. I'm thinking that the questioner smushed two reports into one for the third item in you current example, sot the fact that you got two matches from it is a "feature".